# Validation of viewstate MAC failed machineKey configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am facing the following error,
"validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster"

i know this is a repeated question, but i am unable to find the solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validation of viewstate MAC failed.Application hosted by a Web Farm, ensure <machineKey> configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398954/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-application-hosted-by-a-web-farm-ensure-mac)

Comment: Add machine key in web config!!